# using bing api xslt

Tags: api, xslt, namespaces, bing

I'm trying to use the Bing Image api, but can't manage to get it working.
I'm trying to transform the result, but the transformation does not return anything useful.
I think this is because I'm doing something wrong with the namespaces, as it is something I find terribly confusing in all xml related languages...

here is an example of what I receive from Bing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?pageview_candidate?>
<SearchResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/element" Version="2.2">
<Query>
  <SearchTerms>natalie portman</SearchTerms>
</Query>
<mms:Image xmlns:mms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/multimedia">
  <mms:Total>644000</mms:Total>
  <mms:Offset>0</mms:Offset>
  <mms:Results>
    <mms:ImageResult>
      <mms:Title>Natalie Portman/natalie-portman-83</mms:Title>
      <mms:MediaUrl>http://www.bestidol.pl/natalieportman/slides/natalie-portman-83.jpg</mms:MediaUrl>
      <mms:Url>http://www.bestidol.pl/natalieportman/slides/natalie-portman-83.php</mms:Url><mms:DisplayUrl>http://www.bestidol.pl/natalieportman/slides/natalie-portman-83.php</mms:DisplayUrl>
      <mms:Width>1024</mms:Width>
      <mms:Height>768</mms:Height>
      <mms:FileSize>95173</mms:FileSize>
      <mms:ContentType>image/jpeg</mms:ContentType>
      <mms:Thumbnail>
        <mms:Url>http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=809383506038& amp;id=b829ae4c6df8866b6a07325bedca4bbd</mms:Url>
        <mms:ContentType>image/jpeg</mms:ContentType>
        <mms:Width>160</mms:Width>
        <mms:Height>120</mms:Height>
        <mms:FileSize>3838</mms:FileSize>
      </mms:Thumbnail></mms:ImageResult>
   <mms:ImageResult>
   ... other ImageResults and closing tags.
```

here my curent xslt transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:mms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/multimedia">

<xsl:template match="/">
<list>
   <xsl:for-each select="//mms:ImageResult" >
    <element>
        <image>
            <url><xsl:value-of select="/mms:MediaUrl" /></url>
            <width><xsl:value-of select="/mms:Width" /></width>
            <height><xsl:value-of select="/mms:Height" /></height>
        </image>
    </element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</list>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

does somebody see my mistake(s)?
because this transform returns me:

```
<list xmlns:mms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/multimedia">
   <element>
     <image>
       <url/>
       <width/>
       <height/>
     </image>
   </element>
   ...
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoudnt be...

```
    <url><xsl:value-of select="mms:MediaUrl" /></url>
    <width><xsl:value-of select="mms:Width" /></width>
    <height><xsl:value-of select="mms:Height" /></height>
```

?

Comment: thank you very much, stupid mistake, at least I got the namespace right ;)